# python - Deep imports

Tags: python, import, module, whoosh

I'm working on a project that uses [whoosh](https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/overview). I wish to leave the source tree of whoosh in-place and be able to import from higher levels.

The location of the actual whoosh module is:

```
project\libs\whoosh\src\whoosh
```

I wish to import as:

```
import libs.whoosh
import libs.whoosh.index
etc.
```

It is simple enough to convert each subdirectory into a python module by placing a `__init__.py` file that imports the next subdirectory.

The issue, however, is that whoosh's `__init__.py` does not expose any of its submodules. Therefore `import libs.whoosh.index` only works when whoosh is in the system path; this is a constraint, I do not wish to manipulate the system path nor install whoosh into site-packages.

Ordinarily (when whoosh is on the system path), it seems whoosh's internal imports are named fully; ie, from `project\libs\whoosh\src\whoosh\index.py`:

```
from whoosh import __version__
from whoosh.legacy import toc_loaders
from whoosh.compat import pickle, string_type
from whoosh.fields import ensure_schema
```

legacy, compat and fields are all siblings to index. Importing whoosh through a chain of `whoosh\src\whoosh` breaks its import scheme.

How do I go about this without:

- installing whoosh
- manipulating the system path

Comment: if you don't  want to "manipulate the system path nor install whoosh into site-packages", then use virtualenv. Hacking the package system brings more troubles than polluting site-packages

Comment: But I definitely want to "hack the package system".

Answer (score 0):

You could use add your module path to PYTHONPATH environment variable either persistently or before you run the code.

```
setenv PYTHONPATH $PYTHONPATH:project\libs\whoosh\src
```

Or you could do this in your code:

```
sys.path.append('project\libs\whoosh\src')
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, however, this is explicitly want I didn't want to do.

Comment: Then you could add `whoosh\src\whoosh` as whoosh in your project, thus you won't need neither installing that module nor manipulating system path.